# Inner Join Database Table with Excel file by query in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, excel, amazon-redshift

I need to perform an inner join between a table in Amazon Redshift and an Excel table. The database table is quite large, and I only need to extract the IDs that are in Excel file, which contains a substantial list of IDs (approximately 30,000).

I attempted to include the Excel table directly into the execute function but encountered issues.
How to correctly do that?

```
id_table=df['id']
def query_():
    query =f"""
        SELECT distinct 
        t1.id, t1.value
        FROM table1 t1 
       inner join  (SELECT id2 from %s ) as t2
        on t1.id=t2.id2

    """
    return query

def get_dataframe2():
    query = query_()
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname=database_, host=server_, user=username_, password=password_, port=port_) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(query,(id_table,))
            # cur.execute(query)
            success = False
            while not success:
                try:
                    data = cur.fetchall()
                    success = True
                except:
                    cur.nextset()

    cols = ['id','value']
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "encountered issues"? What did you try? It's probably better to upload the data to a new Redshift table and then use the data.

Comment: I shared the code tried and the error. meanwhile, I was able to fix it. I will detail the answer if anyone has the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Great! You are welcome to add an Answer for your own Question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue, so I wanted to share the code I used in case someone is trying to do the same thing. Please comment or provide another reply if you have a more efficient way, but this is what worked for me.

1. Convert the IDs from the excel file into  a tuple

   id_tuples=tuple(df['id'].drop_duplicates().astype(str).tolist())
2. Inner Join db table with the table created using the below query

   ( SELECT id2 from (  select array{id_tuples} AS  id ) as ids, ids.id as id2) as I

   In summary, this creates a derived table or a subquery named ids, where it converts the id_tuples list into an array and assigns it an alias id. Then, it selects the elements of this array as id2. Finally, it aliases the result as I

The final code is the following

```
id_tuples=tuple(df['id'].drop_duplicates().astype(str).tolist())
def query_():
    query =f"""
        SELECT distinct 
        t1.id, t1.value
        FROM table1 t1 
       inner join  
      ( SELECT id2 from (  select array{id_tuples} AS  id ) as ids, ids.id as id2) as I on I.id2=t1.id
      

    """
    return query

def get_dataframe2():
    query = query_()
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname=database_, host=server_, user=username_, password=password_, port=port_) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(query)
            # cur.execute(query)
            success = False
            while not success:
                try:
                    data = cur.fetchall()
                    success = True
                except:
                    cur.nextset()

    cols = ['id','value']
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```